# Help with multivariable transfer function

Tags: self-learning, control-theory

I am looking to find the transfer function from *w* to *z* in this loop. I have been trying for a while looking all the relationships but just don't know how to express *w* in terms of *r*,*d* and *n* and then express it as a TF with z. I would appreciate a hint on how to solve this.

[image: control loop]
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the closed-loop in $v$ we have
$$v=r-(n+d+GKv)$$
or equivalently
$$v=(\mathbb{I}+GK)^{-1}(r-d-n)$$
Since
$$z=-r+d+GKv$$
we have that
$$z=\big[GK(\mathbb{I}+GK)^{-1}-\mathbb{I}\big]r-\big[GK(\mathbb{I}+GK)^{-1}-\mathbb{I}\big]d-GK(\mathbb{I}+GK)^{-1}n$$
that can be simplified to
$$z=(\mathbb{I}+GK)^{-1}r-(\mathbb{I}+GK)^{-1}d-GK(\mathbb{I}+GK)^{-1}n$$